# Passing variables between files in a project without init

Tags: python, global-variables, python-import

is in Python any way how to initialize the variable only once and then just import it into the remaining modules?

I have following python project structure:

- api

  - v1

    - init.py
  - v2

    - init.py
  - init.py
- logging.py

logging.py:

```
from raven import Client

sentry = None

def init_sentry():
    global sentry
    sentry = 'some_dsn'
```

api/**init**.py

```
from app import logging
logging.init_sentry()

#run flask server (v1,v2)
```

api/{v1,v2}/**init**.py

```
from logging import sentry

    try:
        1 / 0
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        sentry.captureException()
```

In files api/v1/**init**.py and api/v2/**init**.py a get a error NoneType on sentry variable. I know I can call init_sentry in all files when I use it, but I'm looking for a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you misspelled `init.py`, should it be `__init__.py`.

It is bad programming style to pass data between modules with variable. You should use a class or a function to handle shared data. In such manner you have an API, and it is clear what the variable could be modified by other modules.

But for your question: I would (really not) create a module `data.py` with a `shared = {}` dictionary. From other modules, just by importing I can share the data.  By looking if a variable, or just a flag `moduleA_initialized`, you can decide if you need to initialized the module.

As alternative, you can directly write to `globals()` dictionary. Note: this is worse programming practice, and you should check carefully the names, so that there is no conflicts to any library you may use. `gettext` write to it, but is pretty special case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to encapsulate the `sentry` variable and make sure that it is always calling into something, instead of accessing `None`:

#### logging.py:

```
class Sentry(object):

    _dsn = None

    @classmethod
    def _set_dsn(cls, dsn):
        cls._dsn = dsn

    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, item):
        return getattr(cls._dsn)

sentry = Sentry

def init_sentry():
    Sentry._set_dsn('some_dsn')
```

#### Note:

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49097407/7311767) was also correct about the fact that you likely want `__init__.py` not `init.py`.